# Trying to navigate to a webview on my mobile app

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

[image: 1]

That's my code. I am working with expo. This just shows a blank white background but the URL doesn't load up

On expo documentation page. it seems pretty easy but I have no idea if it is cause I am navigating to the webview that's why I am facing this issue. P.S no error or warning is shown

Comment: Are you using a button hence the navigation? That is to say, a user clicks a button, it moves to a webview?

Comment: I am using a pressable for my onpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) create Expo Project

```
expo init rnwebviewnav
```

2.) install expo react navigation from react navigation

```
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

3.) install webview with expo

```
expo install react-native-webview
```

4.) Create a folder called src (for source) and add your files. For me, I added 2 files there Like this

[image: added-h.png]

5.) make sure your package.json looks like this (or has this components as dependencies)

[image: leonid.png]

6.) Make sure your App.js Looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import WebViewPage from "./src/WebViewPage";
import ButtonPage from "./src/ButtonPage";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ButtonPage"
          component={ButtonPage}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="WebViewPage"
          component={WebViewPage}
          options={{ title: "Webview Page" }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

7.) Make sure the page that navigates to the Webview Looks like this

*Button Page*

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const ButtonPage = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const navigateToWebView = () =>{
        navigation.navigate('WebViewPage');
    }

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <Text>ButtonPage</Text>
      <Button onPress={navigateToWebView} title="Click to Navigate" color="#841584" />
    </View>
  )
}

export default ButtonPage

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

8.) Make sure your Webview Page looks thus

*Web View Page*

```
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import WebView from 'react-native-webview'

const WebViewPage = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <WebView 
      source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} 
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default WebViewPage

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

9.) run `npm start` on your terminal to see what you have done so far!

button page

[image: Screenshot-1672342552.png]

webview page

[image: Screenshot-1672342562.png]

I believe I have answered your question :) If yes , pls upvote my answer if it has helped you.